# Changing the marker color when hovering on corresponding element -> Angular 4

Tags: angular, hover

I'm trying to change the color of google marker dynamically when I hover on one of the element that is in different component.
I'm  still learning Angular and I tried using Observables but without any success.

I have `main.view`  component that stores all the cards( I call them events). Here is the part of `main-view.component.ts` code:

```
constructor( private eventService: EventsDataService) {
    }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getEvents();
      }
```

I'm injecting the service that fetches the data for my cards from the server and use `getEvents` method to convert it to JSON data using Observable. Then I use 2 *ngFor directives in `html` template to iterate over this data and fill the cards and markers. Here is the code:

```
main-view.component.html

 <app-event-card *ngFor="let event of events; let i = index"></app-event-card>
  </section>
  <aside class="mapContainer"  [class.fixed]="fixed">
      <agm-map [class.fixed]="fixed"  [latitude]= "latitude"  [longitude]="longitude" >
        <agm-marker *ngFor="let event of events; let i = index"
        [latitude]= "event.location.coordinates[0]"
        [longitude]="event.location.coordinates[1]"
        label="{{event.price +'AUD'}}">
      </agm-marker>
      </agm-map>
  </aside>
```

Now I would like to change the color or any property of the marker when I hover on one of the cards that corresponds to the marker but I have no idea how can I connect the data for those both components.

I would appreciate any  help or tips regarding this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your components look like, but all you need is something like that:

```
<app-event-card (mouseenter)="event.hovered = true" (mouseleave)="event.hovered = false" *ngFor="let event of events; let i = index"></app-event-card>

<aside ...>
  <agm-map ...>
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let event of events; let i = index"
      ...
      [color]="event.hovered ? 'blue' : 'red'">
    </agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</aside>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5lr6o2?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Although it's an old answer: It's incorrect now and was incorrect in the past as well. There was never a color input in the api for agm-marker.

Answer (score 6):

list of markers outside map

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let data of markers" (mouseenter)="updateColor(data.lat)" (mouseleave)="updateColorR(data.lat)">{{data.lat}}</li></ul>
```

markers

```
  <agm-marker 
  *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
  (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
  [latitude]="m.lat"
  [longitude]="m.lng"
  [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
  [iconUrl]="m.icon"
  (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">
```

component

```
updateColor(data:any){
this.markers.map((el,i)=>{
  if(el.lat==data){
    this.markers[i].icon='https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|4286f4';

  }
})
}
updateColorR(data:any){
this.markers.map((el,i)=>{
  if(el.lat==data){
    this.markers[i].icon='https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FF0000';

  }
})
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-x8pqxu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demo